# str.split() inside $(document).ready() does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/MQHkA/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mystring="fusioncharts,om,bdutt";
    var arr = mystring.split(','); //array returned
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      alert(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Would the above code work ?

EDIT---

Well the real code block is this :

```
handle1 = getUrlVars();
if(handle1 == '') {
    $("input#handle1").val('barackobama');
    $("input#handle2").val('aplusk');
    $("input#handle3").val('charliesheen');
    handle1 = 'barackobama,aplusk,charliesheen';
} else {
    alert(handle1);       // this says fusioncharts,om,bdutt
    var queryvals = [];
    queryvals = handle1.split(',');
    alert('length'+queryvals.length);         // *** this says nothing ***
    for(var i = 0; i < queryvals.length; i++) {
        alert(queryvals[i]);                   // *** nothing here too.. ****
    }
}
```

And the entire block is in a $(document).ready()...

Must be some simple error which I'm unable to spot..

Comment: Yes, it works, in my Chrome browser. Which browser is not working?

Comment: I'm using the same -Chrome! Does it work on the jsfiddle site for you ?

Comment: yes this will work, What is your problem, where are u stuck

Comment: Clear your browser cache haha. Works for me too bro.

Comment: The OP's jsfiddle is not wrapped in a document ready.  That is the point of the question.

Comment: @Ray: But it is wrapped in onload in the jsfiddle. Or do you think he just missed that in the sidebar?

Comment: You should have checked your console before posting it to stackoverflow.

Comment: @mu & Ray: I have selected the onDomReady option from the sidebar

Comment: @mu - You're right, of course.  I meant that because he didn't *explicitly* wrap the code with the doc-ready and the missing close, he probably wrote the question asking why it worked in the fiddle (even with the onload he set in the sidebar) but got nothing when explicitly adding the code.  Just a guess, though, but it sounds right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing the closing parentheses other than that it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mystring="fusioncharts,om,bdutt";
    var arr = mystring.split(','); //array returned
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      alert(arr[i]);
    }
}); // this one is missing on yours
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to close off your example with

```
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMU9t/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your parentheses and already have sounded the alarm. Debug your code before asking. Javascript functions work fine. You need to be more attentive.

Comment: I don't see the need for this strong wording here. He already said "Must be some simple error which I'm unable to spot..".